# Simple(st) way to change the option of a select with jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I have javascript or jquery select a certain option in a select area in a form?
With jquery's .attr/.prop?

Comment: You want to change the value of the `select` (select different `option`) or change attributes of an existing `option`?

Comment: @Jakub Michálek I want to change the value of the select (select different option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('select option:eq(X)').attr('selected',true);`

Replace X with the desired one:

http://jsfiddle.net/4jBfs/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idOfElement").val("DesiredValue");
```

Looks simple to me